# RecyclerView ViewHolder creation in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-viewholder

I created a test project to see if I can make a screen that has a lot of content, scrolls vertically, and contains one or more RecyclerViews anywhere throughout.
I am currently using the latest RecyclerView version 25.3.1 and everything works fine while RecyclerView is in a ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://s...content-available-to-author-only...d.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#f00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#ff0" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#f0f" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#0ff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#0f0" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#00f" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Each item layout is just a TextView, and I add test data of variable height into the RecyclerView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int numItems = 60;
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            int numLines = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            String s = "item: " + i;
            for (int j = 1; j < numLines; j++) {
                s += "\nitem: " + i;
            }
            list.add(s);
        }

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        private List<String> list;

        private int numViewHolders;

        MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            numViewHolders++;
            Log.d("Sandbox", "created view holder, total number of view holders: " + numViewHolders);
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView.setText(list.get(position));
            float[] hsv = {(float) (Math.random() * 360), 1, 1};
            int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
            holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView textView;

            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm also keeping track of how many ViewHolders are being created. The big problem here is a ViewHolder is created for every single item in the adapter. In this case, there are 60 items and therefore 60 ViewHolders created.
This pretty much destroys one of the big advantages of RecyclerView. Is there any way to have RecyclerView ViewHolder creation behave properly while in a ScrollView?